# 'Form' generated by Square Connect API is not compatible with LastPass

Tags: square-connect

The ['form'](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/articles/adding-payment-form/) generated by @Square's API is not compatible with [LastPass](https://lastpass.com/), so customers have a harder time paying. Seems the decision to make each 'field' a separate iframe is the problem. Is there any workaround? This is a serious impediment to sales.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I don't believe there's a way around this. The iframe-based form that Square uses is an important security feature. Putting each form field in its own iframe allows Square to ensure that credit card data never interacts with your site, while still allowing you to lay things out as you'd like. Any workaround you could devise would probably be a very bad idea, as it could expose you to PCI regulations.

Comment: PayPal is compatible with LastPass, but tech support is truly awful. Seems the best thing at this time is to give up on Square and process payments using Stripe.